# activating password passwordkey php (MySql)

Tags: php, mysql

I have a loginsystem that works fine, Iget the mail with the activating link, but i think i should change somethin. Have anybody seen this before:

```
$subject = "Confirmation link to your e-mail: $username";
   $header = "Confirmation link to your e-mailt";
   $message = "press to activate link";
   $message .= "http://wwww.yourname.com/confirm.php?passkey=$com_code";

   $sentmail = mail($to,$subject,$message,$header);
```

in the mail i got this:

```
Press link to activate accounthttp://wwww.yourname.com/confirm.php?passkey=e4c4c9e4c43cce28e472243b97085bac
```

Any tip?

Comment: Your code does exactly as it's coded; there's no space. Either add one, or insert a line break.

Comment: should i change this ?

Comment: Even with the missing space, `mail()` sends a text-only email by default, so unless your visitor's email client helpfully interprets the link, they'll just see a piece of text. If you want to be sure of links you need to send an HTML format mail.

Comment: *"should i change this ?"* --- It depends. Do you want those two lines to be on seperate lines? @user2879767 That's easy without having to send as HTML and using your existing code. Unless you want `press to activate link` to be the actual text that's clickable.

Comment: got it to work finaly, ;)

Comment: Ah ok. Well I was preparing something with a few examples below during the time you got it to work. @user2879767

Answer (score 1):

If you want to have a new line between both message, you can use the following:

```
$subject = "Confirmation link to your e-mail: $username";
$header = "Confirmation link to your e-mailt";
$message = "press to activate link 

http://wwww.yourname.com/confirm.php?passkey=$com_code";

$sentmail = mail($to,$subject,$message,$header);
```

or as HTML with a clickable text link:

```
$subject = "Confirmation link to your e-mail: $username";
$headers = "MIME-Version: 1.0" . "\r\n";
$headers .= "Content-type:text/html;charset=utf-8" . "\r\n";

$message = "<a href=\"http://wwww.yourname.com/confirm.php?passkey=$com_code\">Press to activate link</a>";

// or use single quotes
// $message = "<a href='http://wwww.yourname.com/confirm.php?passkey=$com_code'>Press to activate link</a>";

$sentmail = mail($to,$subject,$message,$headers);
```

---

***Sidenote:*** (for HTML version)

The escaped double quote `$message = "<a href=\"` or single quote `$message = "<a href='` for the `href` are important. Otherwise, the pass code's variable will not show.